# How can I specify an extension when using the Picker (specifically .json)

Tags: google-apps-script

My goal is to have the user open a file picker, select a .json file and then have the script read the file.

At the moment I have a picker working, but I cannot figure out how to limit it to just show me files with the .json extension.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

1. To open just a JSON file in picker, you need the below view:

   ```
   new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).setMimeTypes("application/json");
   ```
2. to read the file you picked, you need to grab the ID of the file you picked, and then run it through the below function:

   ```
   function readJson(id) {
     var file =DriveApp.getFileById(id);
     var blob = file.getBlob();
     var asString = blob.getDataAsString();
     var asJson = JSON.parse(asString);
   }
   ```